# Can a symbol have a function, variable, and class?

Tags: functions, variables, eieio

**Q:** can one symbol refer to a function, a variable, and a class?

Elisp is a Lisp-2 in which a symbol can have separate
function and variable values.  So, for example, I can define the
following function and variable:

```el
(defun kittens ()
  "Profess love of kittens."
  (message "I love kittens!"))

(defvar kittens nil
  "A variable to store information about kittens.")
```

And query their respective contents:

```el
(symbol-value 'kittens)       ; => nil
(symbol-function 'kittens)    ; => (lambda nil "Profess love...")
```

However, once I define a *class* with the same name:

```el
(defclass kittens ()
  ((quantity
    :initarg :quantity
    :initform 1000
    :accessor kittens-quantity
    :documentation "How many kittens anyone should strive to own."))
  "Kitten class.")
```

The class appears to supercede the function and the variable:

```el
(symbol-value 'kittens)       ; => kittens
(symbol-function 'kittens)    ; => (lambda (&rest slots) "Create a new object...")
```

So: do classes simply clobber the original function and variable,
or do the original values still exist somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Once you declare a class, Emacs will define a function with the name of that class as a creation function, thereby replacing your old function definition.  In Emacs, `eieio.el` has a macro for `defclass` that goes like so:

```lisp
(defmacro defclass (name superclasses slots &rest options-and-doc)

  ;; A lot of stuff here...

  ;; Non-abstract classes need a constructor.
  `(defun ,name (&rest slots)
     ,(format "Create a new object of class type `%S'." name)
     (declare (compiler-macro
               (lambda (whole)
                 (if (not (stringp (car slots)))
                     whole
                   (macroexp--warn-and-return
                    (format "Obsolete name arg %S to constructor %S"
                            (car slots) (car whole))
                    ;; Keep the name arg, for backward compatibility,
                    ;; but hide it so we don't trigger indefinitely.
                    `(,(car whole) (identity ,(car slots))
                      ,@(cdr slots)))))))
     (apply #'make-instance ',name slots))
```

Note that the macro runs `(defun kittens (&rest slots) ...`.

It should be noted that the variable `eieio-backward-compatibility` (defaulted to `t`) controls whether your `kittens` tracks a variable after `defclass`.

For instance, when I define `puppies` without backward compatibility:

```lisp
(setq-local eieio-backward-compatibility nil)

(defclass puppies ()
  ((quantity
    :initarg :quantity
    :initform 1000
    :accessor puppies-quantity
    :documentation "How many puppies anyone should strive to own."))
  "Puppies class!")

(symbol-function 'puppies)    ; => (lambda (&rest slots) "Create a new object...")
(symbol-value 'puppies)       ; => error: (void-variable puppies)
```

The function will still be overwritten, but if you have a variable set, it can remain.

Comment: That's true for the function, but the variable is only defined if `eieio-backward-compatibility` is non-nil.

Comment: @Stefan: that's super helpful information for my specific use case, but I couldn't find it in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eieio/).  I presume that this variable is going to default to `t` into the distant future.

Comment: For completeness, could @Stefan add his comment as a separate answer, or could cyberbisson incorporate Stefan's comment about the variable value into the original answer?

Comment: Certainly.  It's a good point.